# ActionScript (AS3) object /JSON text input

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, json

I have a problem with ActionScript (AS3) / JSON. There is probably a really simple answer to this, so I apologize if this seems like a really noob question.

What I am trying to do is take multiple text strings, place them into an object and then have that object sent as a JSON string to a server.

Every thing else in my code works fine, accept whenever I input a piece of text into my text input box and send the object, the array produces null entries like so:

```
{"email":null,"last_Name":null,"first_Name":null,"date_of_birth":null,"telephone":null}
```

However if I replace `customer.first_name = inPutfname` with: `customer.first_name = " John";`

Then the array traces back as the following which is what I want:

```
{"email":null,"last_Name":null,"first_Name":John,"date_of_birth":null,"telephone":null}
```

So how do I take the multiple input text strings and place them into the object so that the array reads back as it does in the above example, or ideally like this example:

```
{"email":randomemail@email.com"last_Name":smith,"first_Name":john,"date_of_birth":27/07/1989,"telephone":012343456788}
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var inPutFirstname: String;

var inPutLastname: String;

var inPutEmail: String;

var inPutTelephone: String;

var inPutDob: String;


// changes customer data into an object
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

var customer:Object = new Object;

customer.first_Name =inPutFirstname;

customer.last_Name =  inPutLastname;           PROBLEM AREA?

customer.email = inPutEmail;

customer.date_of_birth = inPutDob;

customer.telephone = inPutTelephone;
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\


//changes customer object into json string

var myJson: String = JSON.stringify(customer);


var myVariableUrl: URLVariables = new URLVariables();
myVariableUrl.data = JSON.stringify(myVariableUrl);

var myRequestUrl: URLRequest = new URLRequest();
var authHeaderUrl: URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("xxxxxx", "xxxxxxx");

myRequestUrl.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
myRequestUrl.data = myJson;
myRequestUrl.url = "website url"

var uload: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
uload.load(myRequestUrl);

uload.load(myRequestUrl);





mySendbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, thefunction1);
// captures text from the input and places them into the customer object
function captureText1(): void {

inPutFirstname = myFirstName.text;
inPutLastname = myLastName.text;
inPutEmail = myEmail.text;
inPutDob = myDob1.text + myDob2.text + myDob3.text;
inPutTelephone = myTele.text;

}

 function thefunction1(event: MouseEvent): void {
 captureText1();
 trace(inPutfname);
 trace(myJson);
}
```

Any Help would be Amazing.

Thanks guys

Comment: If you use Textfield, where is the code? How do you change the value of inPutFirstname for exemple?

Comment: How do you mean? not using Textfield but Textinput. this is at the bottom code. for instance when a user places their first name into the text box, this is then changed into a text string variable after the user clicks on the send button with  inPutFirstname = myFirstName.text; within the capture function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the code for creating the JSON object doesn't seem to be contained in a function, which means it will be executed immediately (considering this is probably code attached to a frame).

What you need to do is to is to wrap the code relating to creating the JSON object into a function, something like this:

*(Please note that there are a lot of ways this code can be structured better, however this should illustrate some core concepts.)*

```
var inPutFirstname: String;
var inPutLastname: String;
var inPutEmail: String;
var inPutTelephone: String;
var inPutDob: String;

function generateJSON():String {
    var customer:Object = new Object();

    customer.first_Name = inPutFirstname;
    customer.last_Name = inPutLastname;
    customer.email = inPutEmail;
    customer.date_of_birth = inPutDob;
    customer.telephone = inPutTelephone;

    return JSON.stringify(customer);
}

function sendJSON(data)
    var myVariableUrl: URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    myVariableUrl.data = JSON.stringify(myVariableUrl);

    var myRequestUrl: URLRequest = new URLRequest();
    var authHeaderUrl: URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("xxxxxx", "xxxxxxx");

    myRequestUrl.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    myRequestUrl.data = data;
    myRequestUrl.url = "website url"

    var uload: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    uload.load(myRequestUrl);
}

mySendbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, thefunction1);

// captures text from the input and places them into the customer object
function captureText1(): void {
    inPutFirstname = myFirstName.text;
    inPutLastname = myLastName.text;
    inPutEmail = myEmail.text;
    inPutDob = myDob1.text + myDob2.text + myDob3.text;
    inPutTelephone = myTele.text;
}

function thefunction1(event: MouseEvent): void {
    // First populate the string variables with user input
    captureText1();

    // Then generate the JSON string
    var jsonData:String = generateJSON();

    // Lastly, send the JSON string
    sendJSON(jsonData);

    trace(inPutfname);
    trace(jsonData);
}
```

Comment: AMAZING Thank you so much walkietokyo. i new it was something along those lines but i just couldn't get my head around it. makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 0):

1st of all, can you add in function captureText1() traces for:

```
trace(myFirstName.text);
trace(myLastName.text);
trace(myEmail.text);
etc...
```

just to be sure that you have proper value in there.
And if you are, instead of using extra variables for that you can do (right after traces):

```
var customer:Object = new Object;
customer.first_Name = myFirstName.text;
customer.last_Name =  myLastName.text;
customer.email = myEmail.text;
customer.date_of_birth = "" + myDob1.text + myDob2.text + myDob3.text;
customer.telephone = myTele.text;

var myJson: String = JSON.stringify(customer);
trace(myJson);
```